# Exact values from Safari's Element selection rulers?

Tags: safari, safari-web-inspector

In the Safari web inspector, I'm using the Element selection tool. When I hover over elements, I see red lines which mark positions on the horizontal and vertical rulers. How do I get the exact values that are marked on the rulers?

[image: Red lines and rulers]